# Get no p-value when making hypothesis test on whether slope coefficient is 1.75

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, lm, hypothesis-test

I have to test the hypothesis of `Ho: ß1 = 1.75`. And I write this:

```
model1<- lm (y - x)
model2<- lm (y - x, offset = 1.75*x)
anova(model1, model2)
```

but I couldn't get a P-value.

[image]

Any ideas? Thank you.

---

**Editor Notice**

This is **not a typo** (so don't close this as typo); OP's ANOVA output shows that he / she manages to run `lm` successfully, so the `-` is likely to be a mistyping. The real issue is with the use of `anova`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a syntax error: use tilde `~` for formula. Read `?lm` and `?formula` for more.

You want to perform **t-test** on a coefficient. The default NULL hypothesis is 0 coefficient. As you are aware of, we can use `offset` or something similar to shift the coefficient.

`summary` will produce a table / matrix for coefficients, and you can use `coef` to extract that table / matrix:

```
coef(summary(lm(y ~ x, offset = 1.75 * x)))
```

---

**Reproducible example**

```
set.seed(0)
xx <- rnorm(100)
yy <- 1.3 * xx - 0.2 + rnorm(100, sd = 0.5)

coef(summary(lm(yy ~ xx, offset = 1.75 * xx)))

#              Estimate Std. Error   t value     Pr(>|t|)
#(Intercept) -0.2243489 0.04814396 -4.659960 9.974037e-06
#xx          -0.3806026 0.05480131 -6.945137 4.170746e-10
```

The p-value for coefficient of `xx` is `~e-10`, so the NULL hypothesis is rejected.

---

## *Why not F-test?*

**Your question was closed as being a typo, but in fact it is more than that.** You definitely don't want `anova` here. The following models are equivalent:

```
m1 <- lm(y ~ x)
m2 <- lm(y ~ x, offset = 1.75 * x)
```

They only differ in coefficient for slope, and everything else is the same (even the standard error of the slope). If you use `anova`,

```
anova(m1, m2)

#Model 1: yy ~ xx
#Model 2: yy ~ xx  ## offset is not shown in formula
#  Res.Df  RSS Df  Sum of Sq F Pr(>F)
#1     98 22.7                       
#2     98 22.7  0 3.5527e-15
```

we indeed see the same model degree of freedom and RSS for both models.

Recall if you have degree of freedom `d1` and `d2` for `m1` and `m2`, F-statistic is

```
( (RSS1 - RSS2) / (d2 - d1) ) / ( RSS2 / (n - d2) )
```

which has F-distribution with degree of freedom `(d2 - d1, n - d2)`. If `d1 = d2` and `RSS1 = RSS2`, how can you construct F-statistic???